# Javascript catch error within console and callback message

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this function which is a search query. This works fine unless the query string name is not detailed enough which then throws up an error message

```
request( url, function (error, data) {
errorText = arguments['0'];
  if (error) {
      callback('Unable to connect to location services!', undefined)
  } else if (errorText.includes('Cannot read property')) {
      callback ('Unable to find location, try another search.', undefined)
  } 
  else {
    callback( {
      data = data.body,
      namePlace: data.suggestions[1].entities[0].name,
      idPlace: data.suggestions[1].entities[0].destinationId,
      })
   } 
})
```

The error message from the console is

```
namePlace: data.suggestions[1].entities[0].name,
                                           ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

I want to be able to capture this error message and callback 'Unable to find location, try another search.'

Comment: Can you provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) preferably in a [Stack snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want to check for is whether `data.suggestions[1].entities` has any entries.  Perhaps something like:

```
else if (data.suggestions[1].entities.length === 0) {
  callback('Unable to find location, try another search.', undefined)
}
```

Depending on how reliable the resulting data structure is, you might also check for `null` or `undefined` values.  But for this particular error it looks like `entities` is defined and an array but just has no entries.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the logical order of the first `if`, otherwise `else if (error)` will prevent `if (errorText.includes('Cannot read property'))`.

Have you previously defined `let request = new Request(<uri>)`?

What is it that you're trying to do?

```
request( url, function (error, data) {
errorText = arguments['0']; // What are you trying to do here?
  if (errorText.includes('Cannot read property')) {
      callback ('Unable to find location, try another search.', undefined)
  } else if (error) {
      callback('Unable to connect to location services!', undefined)
  } else {
    callback( {
      data = data.body, // What are you trying to do here?
      namePlace: data.suggestions[1].entities[0].name, // What are you trying to do here?
      idPlace: data.suggestions[1].entities[0].destinationId,
      })
   } 
}); // <- semicolon here
```